# TFS Parent Child Relationships and display modes

Tags: tfs

I am struggling with TFs, infact am aobut to blue a fuse.

I have would like to display the follow:

Parent Ticket(P1) > Child of Parent(C1) > Child(C2) of Parents Child.

However all i ever see in the Board view is the Parent and the Child of Parents Child, so thats P1 > C2.

What in a funk, driving me pure nuts

Answer (score 1):

Use a tree query, not a parent-child type of query.